# How can I let google scholar find conference name of an arXiv paper?

Tags: conference, arxiv, google-scholar

I uploaded a paper to arXiv, and google scholar made its index.
The paper is then accepted for a conference, but the website of the conference does not have any link to the pdf of the paper.
The search result of google scholar shows that the paper is on arXiv, but it does not show the conference name.
As arXiv suggests, I put the conference name in the "comments" field when I submitted to arXiv. However, it seems like google scholar cannot recognize it.

How can I tell google scholar the conference name of the arXiv paper?

Comment: Does the conference web site list the title of your accepted paper?

Answer (score 2):

Google scholar crawls the web automatically and indexes all the papers that it finds. Your paper will not be listed with the conference name before it is actually published. And since the conference has not taken place in your case, it will not be listed as such (and how should google know that the ArXiV paper and the official versions are *exactly* the same - which they probably aren't?).

So you have to wait until the official version of the paper appeared (e.g., on the publisher's web page). You can then tell Google Scholar to merge the two papers into one in your account.