# I uploaded my paper first on arXiv, but it can not be indexed by google scholar after the paper is officially published in conference

Tags: google-scholar

My paper has been accepted by a conference. Due to the page limit, I uploaded a more extended version of my article on arXiv. My article had been officially published and can be found on acm.org. It was put online by the conference managers before the conference was held 5 months ago (in May 2022). The conference itself had been held a month ago (in September 2022). However, google scholar only shows the arXiv version. No result related to the conference can be found even in "all versions" of my article. How can I make the conference version be indexed?

My situation is different from the previous questions:

- [Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77894/how-can-i-let-google-scholar-find-conference-name-of-an-arxiv-paper) the paper may not be published officially at the conference, yet my paper has already been publically available on the conference website for several months.
- It is certain that my arXiv version and the conference version are different since the arXiv version has more pages. I tried [this solution](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/172958/164010), but I can not find my conference version after I click "Add Articles".

Comment: "_The conference had been held a month ago. My article had been officially published and can be found on acm.org_" When exactly was your paper officially published? A month ago? Or more recent?

Comment: Did you contact google about your problem?

Comment: @Nobody I have updated the post and added a more detailed description of publication time.

Comment: @EarlGrey No, I didn't. It seems no contact methods are provided on google scholar. Do you know which email address should I send to?

Comment: have a look here:
https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/94931002/how-to-contact-google-scholar-how-to-report-errors-is-there-a-phone-number-or-email-address?hl=en
and then ask yourself: "is these company really the one I am taking as objective and reliable? a company that is treating so poorly their *content creators* (science is just a content for the biggest advertising company in the world, Alphabet, when not just a tool to achieve their goals, simply said=EBIT) ?"
Enjoy the science ride and please care less about your google scholar profile / h-index and all that crap :D

Comment: Are other papers from that conference indexed?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations on getting your paper published!

Have you tried updating your arXiv article with a new title, perhaps appending "(extended version)" so that it's clear which one is the short-version for the page-limited conference proceedings and which is the long version for archival reference?

Another thing you might do is to upload both your (extended) arXiv version *and* your (short) conference version to your university's research repository.  That'll make it easy for future researchers to find both versions -- since I'm pretty sure GS is pretty thorough about trawling research repositories, and that it does this trawl reasonably often.  If your academic institution doesn't yet have a research repository, you might consider taking the time required to push for one to be created. See https://qcc.libguides.com/c.php?g=301716&p=2019401.

I'm basing these recommendations by *inferring* Google Scholar's behaviour from three datapoints in my convenience sample [1](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2430429329563559234&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5),[2](https://scholar.google.co.nz/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=12184503453319983725),[3](https://scholar.google.co.nz/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=7178023286636552914).  My inference may be invalid, of course, because of the tiny size of the sample and because Google Scholar's indexing behaviour (as well as the scanty bits of information it reveals about its crawlspace) is subject to change without notice, in any way, at any time.

My sample space:

1. [Google Scholar's cluster for "Large coverage fluctuations in Google Scholar: a case study"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2430429329563559234&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)  (Reading this article would, I suspect, give you further clues as to how GS has behaved in the past.)
2. [Google Scholar's cluster for one of my more obscure conference pubs](https://scholar.google.co.nz/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=12184503453319983725)
3. [Google Scholar's cluster for a working paper](https://scholar.google.co.nz/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=7178023286636552914) I had uploaded to arXiv in 2015.  I didn't bother to upload this working paper to my university's research repository but I see that it was picked up by SAO/NASA ADS.  I'd be a bit surprised if ADS indexes everything in arXiv, but *maybe* it indexed my working paper only after a GS crawler had found a citation to it?

Comment: (I have the impression that GS is biased against paywalled sources, so if there are two differing versions of an article with the same title & author list, it *might* be treating your arXiv version as authoritative and not index the short version where you're expecting to find it... have you looked at GS's "related articles" list for your arXiv version?)